# i have a problem using onChange and catching the event in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get information from an api when i do a selection.
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import { getReservas } from '../../api/reservas';
import '../../../node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import './style.css';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class Page extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { selectedDay: new Date(),
                    reservados: [],
                    valueSelect: ''
                    }
        this.buscaReservas = this.buscaReservas.bind(this);
    }

    buscaReservas(event){
        console.log('element', event);
        getReservas(event.target.value)
        .then( (reservas)=>{
            this.setState({ reservados: reservas });
        });

    }

    render(){
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="contenedorCalendario" className="contenedor-calendario">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sixteen wide column">
                        <select name="prueba" onChange={this.buscaReservas} value={this.state.valueSelect}>
                            { this.props.habitaciones.map((hab) => {
                                return <option key={hab.id} value={hab.id}> { hab.name } </option>
                            }) }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sixteen wide column">    
                        <Calendar
                            selectable={true}
                            views={['month']}
                            culture='es'
                            localizer={localizer}
                            events={ this.state.reservados }
                            date={this.state.selectedDay}
                            onNavigate={(date) => { this.setState({ selectedDay: date })}}
                            startAccessor="start"
                            endAccessor="end"
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Page;
```

I don't understand why the argument event is printed in console like this:

element SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: Event, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}

the html select is rendered ok and the values are ok.

Comment: It's a synthetic react event.
https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 0):

It is synthetic event which ensures cross-browser compatibility.
i.e. It will work on all browsers.